# How to clear the cache in the requests_cache package

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I clear the cache in the python `requests_cache` module? I have a project, but if a site gets updated it needs a new response, so how can I make make it so it only fetches one response per run, but uses the same cache name

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you have tried with, then we can better understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: Are you sending an `If-Modified-Since` so that the server might know to respond with a 304?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either set it to expire after a certain amount of time with the optional parameter `expire_after`, or you could manually clear it with `session.cache.clear()`.

From the [requests_cache docs](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html):

```py
session = CachedSession('example_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=60)
session.cache.clear()
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).